# how to cover trigger in test class I am very new to slaesforce

Tags: testing, triggers, apex

```
trigger contacttrigger on Contact (after insert, after delete, after undelete) {
      Set<Id> Ids = new Set<Id>();
          if(trigger.isInsert || trigger.isUndelete){
            for(Contact con:trigger.new){
                if(con.Id!= null){
                    Ids.add(con.Id);
                } } }
         if(trigger.isDelete){
            for(Contact con:trigger.old){
                if(con.Id!= null){
                    Ids.add(con.Id);
                }}}
             if(!Ids.isEmpty()){
            List<Account> accList = [SELECT Id, NoOfContacts__c, (SELECT Id FROM Contacts) FROM Account WHERE Id IN : Ids];
                if(!accList.isEmpty()){
                List<Account> updateAccList = new List<Account>();
                for(Account acc:accList){
                    Account objAcc = new Account(Id = acc.Id, NoOfContacts__c = acc.Contacts.size());
                    updateAccList.add(objAcc);
                }
                if(!updateAccList.isEmpty()){
                    update updateAccList;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

hello every one I am very new to salesforce Please guide me how to cover this trigger in test class thank you

Answer (score 0):

*You must pick report message box "SQL report service system" another on mobile site.*
Triggered as Reporting Monthly.
trigger contacttrigger on Contact (after insert, after delete, after undelete) { Set Ids = new Set(); if(trigger.isInsert || trigger.isUndelete){ for(Contact con:trigger.new){ if(con.Id!= null){ Ids.add(con.Id); } } } if(trigger.isDelete){ for(Contact con:trigger.old){ if(con.Id!= null){ Ids.add(con.Id); }}} if(!Ids.isEmpty()){ List accList = [SELECT Id, NoOfContacts__c, (SELECT Id FROM Contacts) FROM Account WHERE Id IN : Ids]; if(!accList.isEmpty()){ List updateAccList = new List(); for(Account acc:accList){ Account objAcc = new Account(Id = acc.Id, NoOfContacts__c = acc.Contacts.size()); updateAccList.add(objAcc); } if(!updateAccList.isEmpty()){ update updateAccList; } } } }

Comment: sorry i didn't get you

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).